# Topological theory on matrices

Tags: general-topology, matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can anyone suggest me a good book for matrix topology
With more number of problems
Thanking you

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific. The space of all $n\times m$ real matrices is homeomorphic to $R^{nm}$ and there is not much else one can say here. People study spaces of matrices satisfying various further restrictions (like rank restrictions) and there is huge literature on, say, topology of matrix groups, etc.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: I respectfully disagree. There are topologists who are/were interested in topology of naturally defined sets of matrices (e.g. the unitary group, discriminant locus, etc. Consider for instance: J.F. Adams, P. Lax, and R.S. Phillips, On matrices whose real linear combinations are nonsingular, Proc. A.M.S. 16 (1965), 318-322.  At the same time, a book that OP is asking for does not exist.

Comment: Just a footnote: "(reference-request)" is a good tag for such questions.

Comment: @user254665 Don't hesitate to edit the question in such a case. I just dit it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I do not think there is a book on matrix topology (which I understand as "topology of various natural sets of matrices given by matrix equations/inequalities"), along the lines of your question: Not because there is not much to say, but since the subject is way too vast and there is no common theme to organize the material. It would be nice if somebody wrote a "cook-book" style textbook on this though (similar to "cook-books" on ODEs and PDEs). Nevertheless, what you can do is:

1. Look at the right hand side column in this question page for answers to various questions on topology of sets of matrices.
2. Type "topology matrices" in the search box in the upper right corner of this page. You will find 280 (!) links to MSE questions (and answers) which may serve as a good source of problems (and solutions).